# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when creating appxUpload file

Tags: uwp, package, bundle, appxmanifest

I am creating a appxUpload file for my UWP project release. I have already Uploaded more than one bundle files to the Microsoft Store. 
When I am building/rebuilding solution, no errors are being triggered.

But, whenever I start creating a appxUpload file, I get following error:

**Error: Cannot open 'C:\Project\Dekstop\obj\Release\Desktop.exe' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Project\Dekstop\obj\Release\Desktop.exe' because it is being used by another process.' Packager.**

In the AppPackages folder of Windows Packaging project( Packager), Dependencies and Packager_2.2.2.0_x64.appxsym file gets created but after that I receive above error and no other files are getting generated.

I deleted all the obj folder from all projects and tried rebuilding solution. I checked the build configuration manager, here too everything seems to be proper.

please guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to delete package and re-launch Visual Studio create package again.

Comment: Thanks, I emptied AppPackages folder to clear previously created bundle files and other related files. Also, I closed and reopened VS multiple times. I also tried creating bundle file on my clients system but on his system too same error is appearing and it always failed to create package file. The Worst part is, this process takes too long to create package file and all of sudden it gives some weird error messages.

Comment: Please try to check if msbuild running in the task manager, and kill it and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, Finally I resolved this issue by renaming the exe file that was causing this issue. And this successfully created the package file.